# grep -w with modified word-constituent characters

Tags: grep

I am using grep -w for exact word match. My problem is grep -w considers only letters, digits and underscore as word-constituent characters. But I want all other characters except space to be word-constituent characters. Here is my text file, output and desired output.

File : file1.txt

```
clk_file help
co <clk_file> help2
code_error help3
```

Command : grep -w clk_file file1.txt

Output :

```
clk_file help
co <clk_file> help2
```

Desired Output :

```
clk_file help
```

Can anyone tell me what should I use to get desired output. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "word-constituent characters"?

Comment: Post your `grep` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is not enough for this, I believe.

This `awk` is a workaround:

```
$ awk '{f=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i == "clk_file") f=1} if (f) print}' file
clk_file help
```

It loops through all the words of the line and sets a flag `f=1` in case the exact word `clk_file` matches one of them. Then, it prints the line if the flag was set.

---

In case you want the pattern to be a variable, use `-v` as this:

```
$ myvar="clk_file"
$ awk -v patt=$myvar '{f=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i == patt) f=1} if (f) print}' file
clk_file help
```

This is because it is not the same a awk variable and a bash variable. To use a bash variable in awk you need this `-v` assignment.

Comment: I got an idea from Avinash Raj solution.
If I use grep -w "clk_file " file1 , I think I can always get desired output.
Am I correct ?

Comment: Well it will work unless the word is on the last position of the line, because there won't be a space at the end. It is fine for the rest of cases. Also, `co <clk_file help2` would also match incorrectly, because you are not checking the value in the left of `clk_file`.

Comment: Thanks. I really missed that.

Comment: These are edge cases, but it is good to take them into consideration. That's why `grep` alone needs many conditions to make it work (see sat's good answer) or you have to go to more powerful tools like awk or sed.

Comment: I have to read values from a file. So value will be in a variable.
Say I save value in variable a
set a= clk_file
awk '{f=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i == $a) f=1} if (f) print}' file
It does not give desired output.

Comment: It worked. Can u please tell me the reason for assigning a new variable 'patt'

Comment: @PratikKumar the name doesn't really matter, it is just the fact that a bash variable cannot be read within an awk script unless assigned. And this `patt` is the value of the bash variable within the awk script. It is very handy because you can also assign bash values like this: `awk -v mydate="$(date)" 'BEGIN {print mydate}'`

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\(^clk_file \| clk_file$\| clk_file \)/p' yourfile
```

With `grep`:

```
grep '\(^clk_file \| clk_file$\| clk_file \)' yourfile
```

As @AvinashRaj commented, If your `grep` supports `-P` option, then you no need to escape `|` , `(` and `)`. Simply write as,

```
grep -P '(^clk_file | clk_file$| clk_file )' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
clk_file help
help clk_file
co <clk_file> help2
code_error help3
help1 clk_file help2

$ sed -n '/\(^clk_file \| clk_file$\| clk_file \)/p' file
clk_file help
help clk_file
help1 clk_file help2

$ grep '\(^clk_file \| clk_file$\| clk_file \)' file
clk_file help
help clk_file
help1 clk_file help2
```

If your search value is in variable,

```
$ myval="clk_file"
$ grep "\(^${myval} \| ${myval}$\| ${myval} \)"
clk_file help
help clk_file
help1 clk_file help2
```

Comment: In my case value is in a variable.

set a=clk_file

grep -P "(^$a | $a$ |$a)" complete_config_with_options.txt
It shows an error

Comment: Use this: `grep -P "(^$a | $a$| $a )" file`

Comment: I am getting an error "Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters".
I have checked $a by command echo $a, I got an output clk_file

Comment: Problem is with ${myval}$\ .
It tries to find a variable '\' because of $\